# How to test laravel app with dusk that uses webcam for reading qrcode

Tags: laravel, qr-code, webcam, laravel-dusk

As the title says, how can I test laravel app with dusk that uses webcam for reading qrcode?

I have an app that allows the user to login using qrcode. I want to test it using laravel dusk. How?

Currently using Laravel 5.6

Comment: How do you access the webcam? With  `getUserMedia()`?

Comment: I really don't know how to begin actually. I just use a js plugin that when triggered accesses the webcam and is ready to read any qrcode you show to the webcam. I'm using this plugin: https://github.com/schmich/instascan

Comment: The plugin uses `getUserMedia()`. I doubt that it's possible to *really* test it with Dusk. You can try mocking the used functions, take a look at [this](https://testrtc.com/manipulating-getusermedia-available-devices/).

Answer (score 0):

Add this arguments to the `DuskTestCase` file:

```
$options = (new ChromeOptions)->addArguments(collect([
   '--use-fake-device-for-media-stream',
   '--use-file-for-fake-video-capture=example.mjpeg')
]));
```

The fake file should be mjpeg for video capture.